# Windows не находит пакет при запуске скрипта Python

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

Создал bat файл для вызова скрипта python. Скрипт писался в IDE PyCharm.
Содержание bat файла:

```
@py  C:\Users\pc\Desktop\PY\Password\PassManager.py 
@pause
```

Получаю ошибку:

> File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\PY\Password\PassManager.py", line 6, in
>   
>       import pyperclip

В самой IDE скрипт отрабатывает нормально.
Насколько я понимаю, Windows использует не тот интерпретатор.
[image: Путь прописанный в IDE]

Добавил в скрипт `print(sys.executable)`
и получил:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe

То-есть насколько я понимаю моё предположение верно?
Если да, то как заставить windows использовать нужный интерпретатор и решить проблему с нахождением пакета?

Comment: А что вам мешает использовать нужный интерпретатор раз путь до него уже выяснили?

Comment: Нужный это который из?
Не совсем понимаю как заставить использовать WINDOWS нужный интерпретатор? в это и есть суть вопроса
Или правильнее использовать тот который "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe"
Или вообще есть неизвестный мне третий, который и нужно использовать?

Comment: Вы сами написали *"Добавил в скрипт print(sys.executable) и получил:"* - вот и используйте путь к тому интерпретатору, с которым скрипт работает. Вместо какого-то левого алиаса `py` подставляйте полный путь и все.

Comment: В pycharm вы используете виртуальное окружение питона (в каталоге venv, там же живёт пакет pyperclip), а в bat-файле вы используете 'системный' интерпретатор. Либо активируйте виртульное окружение в бат-файле, либо доустановите pyperclip в `системный`

Answer (score 0):

Думаю что правильно будет проставить в начало py скрипта шебэнг, он отрабатывает как в linux так и в windows. На всякий случай прочитайте вот эту статью https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines
В вашем случае это будет

(#! /usr/bin/python3.7-64)